# Asp.Net SessionState CreatedDate equals LockDate

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, session, cookies, session-state

I use the SQLServer mode of SessionState. It works locally but when I publish to web server the sessions dont work. The only difference that I was able to find was the CreatedDate and LockDate of session records... they have the exact same dateTime value.

e.g.
Created:       2013-09-30 18:57:45.860
Expires:       2013-09-30 19:27:45.860
LockDate:      2013-09-30 18:57:45.860
LockDateLocal: 2013-09-30 13:57:45.860
LockCookie:    1
Timeout:       30
Locked:        0

On my local server all the lockdates are bigger than CreatedDate values.
I cant figure out why are the lockdates equal to Createddates, maybe that's why I dont have sessions.

Comment: Likely request coming in is either not completing or failing in a way where the session doesn't get unlocked.

Comment: How can I figure out what the issue is?

Comment: oh, actually looks like it is probably fine. `Locked=0` says that it's unlocked. `LockCookie=1` means that there's only been one lock done, so likely you just see someone who has only hit one page, and then didn't do anything else (or at least didn't do anything else on a page that has session)

Comment: I connected to my local session database and the issue is still there. That means the DB is good. Something must be wrong with my web server...